# How to upload images to firebase without using an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

How do I upload images to firebase without an HTML form, I need to use code only.
I have tried some ways myself but the files fail to preview they're corrupted I guess.
I'm developing my App in React and I need a way to upload images to firebase without an HTML form

I tried:

```
await uploadBytes(storageRef, '../images/image.jpg')
```

I also tried:
`const metadata ={ contentType:'image/jpeg' }`
and also

```
const metadata ={
  contentType:'image/svg+xml'
}
await uploadBytes(storageRef, '../images/image.jpg', metadata)
```

Comment: Please share more code such as what creates `storageRef` etc. There is not enough information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to upload a file to Cloud Storage for Firebase with just a local path as you do here `uploadBytes(storageRef, '../images/image.jpg')`.

If you pass a string as the second argument, you will have to call `uploadString` and the second argument has to be the base64 encoded data that you want to upload.

If you want to upload a file based on its path, you will have to either create a `File` reference to that file, or read its data into a `Blob` and then pass that to `uploadBytes`.

All of these are covered in the Firebase documentation on [uploading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string), so I recommend keeping that handy.

Answer (score 0):

use the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage and the `FileReader` API in JavaScript.

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

const handleFileUpload = (file) => {
  const storageRef = ref(storage, "images/" + file.name);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: file.type,
  };
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  reader.onload = async (event) => {
    const buffer = event.target.result;
    await uploadBytes(storageRef, buffer, metadata);
  };
};
```